# Errors for nested resource not displaying even if I'm using "target"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following:

**routes.rb:**

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :replies
  end
```

**replies_controller.rb:**

```
class RepliesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @reply = @post.replies.build(params[:reply])
    @reply.user_id = current_user.id
    if @reply.save
      flash[:success] = "reply created!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end
  end
```

**replies/_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.replies.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object, target: @reply %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Enter reply content" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Reply", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**posts/show.html.erb:**

```
 <div class="span8">
    <%= render 'replies/form' %>
  </div>
```

**shared/error_messages.html.erb:**

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>* <%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure why the errors messages for the `replies` are not displaying since I'm using `target: @reply` (:content and :user_id are required).

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In create method's **else** section you have to render the post_path(@post) not redirect the post_path(@post)

try this in **else** part of create section

```
render :template => 'posts/show'
```

So that your current **@reply** object will persist for your error messages.

**redirect_to post_path(@post)** will redefine **@reply** object in show action (I assume you have defined @reply object there).

In **posts/show** action, build your reply object there and assign it to @reply instance object.

```
@reply = @post.replies.build
```

Now in **replies/_form.html.erb**:

change @post.replies.build to @reply

i.e

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.replies.build]) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for([@post, @reply]) do |f| %>
```

Also assign **@reply** to **object** variable while rendering 'shared/error_messages' partial,

```
<%= form_for([@post, @reply]) do |f| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'shared/error_messages', :locals => {:object => @reply} %>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Enter reply content" %>
  </div>
 <%= f.submit "Reply", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Also make partial for error_messages in shared folder (**shared/_error_messages**). In this partial paste your code which is in **shared/error_messages**

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
   <ul>
   <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
     <li>* <%= msg %></li>
   <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Strnge, I tried that and I got this: `Missing template /posts/298 with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. ` But there isn't any missing template, its just `render post_path(@post)`.

Comment: I just edited my code. Just replace with **render :template => 'posts/show'**. Please check again.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but still not working: `'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.
`

Comment: maybe because the show action in your suggestion is not pointing to the current post?

Comment: oh, sorry. The page does render, but there're still no error messages.

Comment: getting this now: `undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
`

Comment: I edited code again. Please go step by step and make changes as I said  in my code. I think this change should solve your problem.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. It worked. But I realized I had to add `@replies = @post.replies.paginate(page: params[:page])` above `render :template => 'posts/show'` otherwise `@replies` return `nil` even if it is already defined in the post show action. Strange.